# Sending jquery variable while loading a php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new in programing websites so forgive my lack of knowledge...
I'd like to load some content from database without reloading page. So using jquery I can load php file which conects with database

```
 $("body").on("click",".editpages", function(){
    $('#pagesedit').load('/templates/admin/pages.php #edit');
 });
```

Problem is that I need to send one variable that I can use it in my php file. How can I do that?

Comment: use query strings `http://example.com/pages.php?var=hello`, then access thru `$_GET['var']` in PHP, `#` hash doesn't get set in server side

Comment: You can also use `ajax` methods for variable passing

Answer (score 1):

**Use Jquery Ajax**

```
 $("body").on("click",".editpages", function(){
  $.post( "templates/admin/pages.php", { yourVariable: "John" })
 .done(function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Id recommenced looking at [PHP Get Varriables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).
First just pass the varriable to your php page.

```
$("body").on("click",".editpages", function(){
  $('#pagesedit').load('/templates/admin/pages.php?YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME');
});

<?php
  if isset(htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"])) {
    // DO WHATEVER IN PHP
  }
?>
```